# Combine overline character with number

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, unicode, special-characters

According to what I've read pressing Ctrl + Shift + u and then enter the Unicode number, here 203E and then entering the character to combine with, i.e. 6 should result in the correct symbol, but I just end up with the overline itself and not the combination.

1̅

2̅

3̅

Specifically I want to produce one with six. Overline or Macron.

Comment: You want this `1⁶`? or this `1⁻⁶`?

Comment: No superscript, I want a bar over the number as you'd see in mathematics with a repeated number. I.e. 1.6666666666.. is represented as 1.6 where the 6 has a bar over it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, diving into [Unicode 13.0 Character Code Charts](http://unicode.org/charts/), and specifically [Combining Diacritical Marks](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf), I found this:

```
0305 → ‾ (combined)
```

meaning you combine the symbol with another, so you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, the underlined `u` appears, enter `0305`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then you enter the number, the `6` in the example.

If I copy paste in here, it just copies the `6`, apparently satckexchange doesn't allow those type of characters, but here's a screenshot from a terminal:

[image]

For now it's the closest I can get, maybe this helps you.

Comment: For me this produces this character here ざ

Comment: That's maybe related to the unicode set in (your terminal?), it has to be UTF-8.

Comment: This is Gnome Terminal, it says under Compatibility > Encoding > UTF-8. In the meantime, would you mind pasting the 6 here? I know you said StackExchange doesn't allow it but if you look in my original post I did that with 1, 2 and 3. Maybe it's not allowed as code paste?

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot to mention that you have to press enter after the 0305, and then the 6... sorry for that, I'll update the answer.

Comment: This creates two characters for me:  ̅6 It looks almost the same but the characters in my original post consist of just one.

Comment: It's okay though. The unicode character looks really bad in most fonts anyway. I decided to go with 16 ⅔ instead of writing 1. ̅6 Leaving this question for pure curiosity though